# Automate the FTP process

Tags: ftp, solaris

What is the best way to automate the ftp process. I mean can a script be written which when executed would ftp to a remote system and fetch files with out human intervention.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/), which is highly scriptable (see this [tutorial](http://tutorials.papamike.ca/pub/lftp.html#scripts)).

Of course, you can also write an adapted FTP client using perl/ruby/python/your-prefered-scripting-language.

Comment: I agree. lftp is the best tool to use. Even supports parallel ftp processes and automation of sftp.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use wget to do such a thing:

WGET is free so you can grab that and check the help file

Something like:

```
wget -user=username -pass=password ftp://ftp.moose.com/download.zip
```

Obviously usable with variables in a script etc.

Just noticed this is for solaris, so not sure if this would work.

Comment: It might be installed in /usr/sfw/bin, which is probably not in your search path by default.

If you can't find it there, look on sunfreeware.com.

Answer (score 2):

There are Perl packages for this purpose. For instance CPAN 
modules [Net::Lite::FTP](http://search.cpan.org/~eyck/Net-Lite-FTP-0.54/lib/Net/Lite/FTP.pm) and [Net::FTP](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/libnet-1.22/Net/FTP.pm).

It will allow your script to make decisions based on information 
from the server. E.g. if the file name is not constant (may 
contain a date or a version number) then the script can 
process a directory listing before deciding which file to 
download.

I have succesfully used it for automating 
downloading/updating of large molecular sequence databases.

Answer (score 1):

The Solaris `ftp` command can be automated with a netrc(4) file. The **macdef init** is the key. sample:

> cat ~/.netrc
>      machine remote-host1.domain.com login my-ftp-account
>      password password4host1
>      macdef init
>      cd
>      /pub/DOWNLOAD get readme
>
> default login anonymous password my-email@mail.domain.com

### Notes:

1. The two blank lines after the init macro definition are important,
2. This also automates an interactive ftp session to remote-host1.

Your script can create the **netrc** file before it calls ftp.

Answer (score 1):

I like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se) the best:

> curl is a command line tool for transferring files with URL syntax, supporting FTP, FTPS, HTTP, HTTPS, SCP, SFTP, TFTP, TELNET, DICT, LDAP, LDAPS and FILE. curl supports SSL certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication (Basic, Digest, NTLM, Negotiate, kerberos...), file transfer resume, proxy tunneling and a busload of other useful tricks.

Very handy for all your URL-fetching needs.

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten a lot of recommendations already to use something different than FTP. That's fair, because scripting FTP is a little annoying, but it's not necessarily portable, nor is it teaching you anything new.

It's actually quite simple to script by directing commands to ftp from STDIN. This sort of thing works for many kinds of tools.

```
cd /target
ftp -n host <<EOF
USER falken
PASS joshua
cd place
binary
get file
bye
EOF
echo 'hi! um... what'\''s this all about again? I am done.'
```

The login part could be automated by adding information to the script owner's `~/.netrc` file. In fact, if you [`man netrc`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=netrc&category=4&russian=4) you'll learn a lot about automating `ftp`.

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris you can also use *expect* automation tool. Of course you should install it first. For FTP you can find an example in [Wikipedia article on Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: `expect` works on several platforms

Answer (score 0):

I've written one once for our needs,

`#!/bin/sh`

hostname="IP-ADRESS"

port="21"

username="serverfault"

password="serverfalut"

storage_path="DESTINATION"

current_date="$(date +%Y%m%d)"

$remotefile="REMOTE-FILE"

ftp -in $hostname $port << EOF

quote user $username

quote pass $password

binary

get $remotefile $storage_path/

delete $output_dir/output$current_date.tar.gz

quit

close

EOF

exit 0

Answer (score 0):

ncftp usually includes ncftpget and ncftpput, which would be suitable for inclusion in scripts.  They can usually be built from source, or check csw or sunfreeware.

Answer (score 0):

I typically just use ftp with an authentication file .netrc and then cat everything into it.
For example

```
cat >> EOF | ftp
open ftpserver
mget *
bye
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

[NcFTP Client](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/)